# Is $\mathcal{B} = \{f^{-1}(A) : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ or not?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $(Y, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $f$ map $X$ into $Y$, but do not assume that $f$ is one-to-one. Define$$\mathcal{B} = \{f^{-1}(A) : A \in \mathcal{A}\}.$$Is $\mathcal{B}$ a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ or not?

Comment: At which point are you stuck? The whole problem is bascially about showing that set operations commute with preimages